# Creating mutually recursive local functions with metadata in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Suppose I want to define two mutually recursive functions within a local scope. I can do this with letfn:

```
(letfn 
  [(f [x] (if (= x 0) (g x) true))
   (g [x] (if (= x 1) (f x) false))]
 (f 0))
```

But `letfn` is quite restricted, compared to `let`, as it accepts only "function specs," not arbitrary expressions. My question is: what if I want to attach metadata (using `with-meta`) to both `f` and `g`, so that within `f`, I can read `g`'s metadata, and within `g`, I can read `f`'s metadata? Is this possible in Clojure?

(For context, I am trying to implement a `fn`-like macro that automatically attaches certain metadata to the function being created. I'd like these auto-annotated `fn`s to be instantiable wherever a normal Clojure function is, including inside a `letfn`. But I don't see how I can define a `letfn`-like macro that attaches the metadata, because it would ultimately have to desugar to `letfn`, which cannot attach metadata.)

Comment: What is the purpose of all this? Attaching metadata to functions is rarely useful, and I imagine it would be even less useful inside a single lexical scope, where all the nearby functions "know about" each other anyway.

Comment: @amalloy The use case is to embed a new language in Clojure. The "entry points" to the language are special macros with the same syntax as `fn`/`letfn`/`defn`, but which attach additional metadata to the defined function object. Functions in the language can be executed like regular Clojure functions, but also executed in alternative ways--for those, the metadata is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget about `with-local-vars`:

```
  (with-local-vars [f (fn [x] (if (= x 0) (g x) true))
                    g (fn [x] (if (= x 1) (f x) false))]
    (reset-meta! f {:f 3})
    (reset-meta! g {:g 2})
```

with results:

```
(f 0) => false
(f 1) => true

f           => #<Var: --unnamed-->
(var-get f) => #object[tst.demo.core$fn__20698$fn__20699 0x1eb2d718 "tst.demo.core$fn__20698$fn__20699@1eb2d718"]
(meta f)    => {:f 3}
(meta g)    => {:g 2}
```

You can also use `var-get` and `var-set` to access/change the value of the local vars.

Comment: Neat. I had not imagined this use case for `with-local-vars`. It seems a bit against the intended use case, but it does get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the following solution, in which `letfn` is used to define thunks that evaluate to the actual functions `f` and `g`:

```clj
(letfn [(f-thunk [] 
          (with-meta (fn f [] (let [g (g-thunk)] (meta g))) {:f 3})) 
        (g-thunk [] 
          (with-meta (fn g [] (let [f (f-thunk)] (meta f))) {:g 2}))]
  (let [f (f-thunk) g (g-thunk)]
    [(f) (g)]))
```